# Where to find fast DOF shader in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, depth-of-field

I'm looking for fast Dof shader for BGE use. Maybe someone knows, where to find very similar to "Life is Strange" one. DOF could be without autofocus feature, I want simple like distance Dof like one. Would be great if it also has a bokeh effect.

Look like in this video...
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vmm0o1j68ukwvlr/My%20Movie1.mp4

or in pictures;

[image: This]
[image: This]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What About this one?
http://devlog-martinsh.blogspot.com.es/search/label/DoF

or 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aehC81cYrjY

regards